# window open issue

Tags: javascript, html

I have open one pop up window with window.open().
Now in this new pop up window there is one link.

What I want is, when I click on link in pop up window, new window should open but in **parent windows' new tab**.

Can it possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to communate with main window you can use the `opener` property allowing the sub-window to access document content or access variables from within the main window. same-origin security policy will apply.

eg in main window

```
<script>
 function openNew(){
   var subWin = window.open("popup.htm", "sub", "height=400,width=300");
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Open popup" onclick="openNew()" />
```

And in your popup that you wanna click for example and change the main window.

```
<input type="button" value="Change main window location" onclick="opener.location.href='http://www.example.com/test2'" />
```

Comment: I want to open new window not in opener window........BUT in NEW TAB of OPENER window....